# Generating and evaluating models for String -> String functions in Z3

Tags: z3, z3py

I have the following program that applies simple key = value constraints to a function from String to String:

```py
from z3 import *
map = Function('map', StringSort(), StringSort())
c1 = map(StringVal('key1')) == 'value1'
c2 = map(StringVal('key2')) == 'value2'
c3 = map(StringVal('key3')) == 'value3'
c4 = map(StringVal('key4')) == 'value4'
s = Solver()
s.add(And(c1, c2, c3, c4))
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

The output of the model is as follows:

```
[map = [Concat(Unit(Char),
               Concat(Unit(Char),
                      Concat(Unit(Char), Unit(Char)))) ->
        "value1",
        Concat(Unit(Char),
               Concat(Unit(Char),
                      Concat(Unit(Char), Unit(Char)))) ->
        "value2",
        Concat(Unit(Char),
               Concat(Unit(Char),
                      Concat(Unit(Char), Unit(Char)))) ->
        "value3",
        Concat(Unit(Char),
               Concat(Unit(Char),
                      Concat(Unit(Char), Unit(Char)))) ->
        "value4",
        else -> "value1"]]
```

This is sort of strange, but presumably it is just a limitation of Z3's representation of elements of the domain of a function.

The hope is I can evaluate a Z3 expression on a concrete constant value of a function in a model; however, I cannot figure out how to do that. The [Eval](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/class_microsoft_1_1_z3_1_1_model.html#adb3e130c7456717c92dc64cf899e22b4) method from the Python reference docs is nowhere to be found in the namespace. I've done something like this before [with the C# bindings](https://github.com/Z3Prover/FirewallChecker/blob/c5d37c6e58599f33b28009034920fc0ee46f0dbe/FirewallQueryCmd/Program.cs#L60) so I know it is possible.

Comment: Oops I was using String instead of StringVal... silly mistake, will edit question

Comment: You have to wrap the right-handsides in `StringVal` as well. You're also missing a final closing parenthesis at the very last line. It's important to keep the code-segments valid for people trying to understand/help with them.

Comment: @alias this is actually an issue I've found, where the API is inconsistent with when you do or do not have to wrap things in `StringVal`. In this case `==` seems to work perfectly well without `StringVal` wrapping, or is it not?

Comment: It doesn't work for me unless I wrap it in `StringVal`.

Comment: This is really an issue with Python, not z3. Unfortunately the Python bindings are "duck"-typed; meaning the library tries to make sense of things based on what you pass; but it's an impossible job to be consistent always. (Numbers are treated better than strings, as you found. But then integers and reals and floats get confused occasionally.) It's best to be always explicit. Bindings from other languages, such as Haskell, do not suffer from this problem, due to their strong static typing guarantees.

Comment: @alias Interesting, what version of python and Z3 are you using? I'm using python 3.9.6 on Windows, with Z3 4.8.12. Wonder what could be causing the difference in behavior. I agree it is best to be explicit though.

Comment: 4.8.13 fails. But I also tried with version compiled from GitHub master yesterday and it works there. Not sure what would cause that, since I don't think the Python bindings have been rather stable for a while. Python 2.7.18 on Mac. In any case, wrapping in `StringVal` is the safest way to go, given the rather weakly-typed nature of Python itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is essentially tradition for my Z3 questions at this point, a few more minutes of messing around revealed you can do this as follows:

```py
s.model().eval(expr)
```

The `Eval` function in the python documentation is actually listed as a member function of `Model`, which is easy to miss.

Per the comment from @alias it is actually best practice to use

```py
s.model().evaluate(expr, model_completion = True)
```

to reduce surprises.

Comment: In addition, the `evaluate` method (which is an alias for `eval`) takes an optional parameter `model_completion`, which you can set to `True`. This is the common use case, as z3 models will not include values for constants that the solver didn't assign any value to, if it happens that it didn't matter for satisfiability. To reduce variability and surprises, always use the `model_evaluate` parameter, setting it to `True`. This is especially important if you are looping over results to collect other satisfying elements.

Comment: Also, the documentation looks good to me: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/z3py_8py_source.html#l06348. But of course, documentation can always be improved.

Comment: @alias I'm talking about [this](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/class_microsoft_1_1_z3_1_1_model.html#adb3e130c7456717c92dc64cf899e22b4) method, which does not seem to exist. edit - ah I see it's listed as a member function of Model, which I missed out when I jumped straight to it. Nevermind then.